# Angular httpClient: Reformat date in json

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object with a property of kind date. If I post it with httpClient.post(...) the date property has it's natural string representation. How can I adopt it to a format that the server understands?

Comment: I think you can send it in milisecond way to server and server can interpret it back to the format required.

Comment: server only accepts "DD-MM-YYYY"

Comment: I think you can use the angular pipes to convert it into the date format you need and pass it to server , https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: convert the string to Date on webservice with whatever language your webservice is written on.

Comment: could you give me an example how to overwrite the serialization? How do I get from myObject.date to {"date": "12-12-2012"}?

Comment: check my edited answer if that helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make use of this to convert it into the format you need and send it over to the server.

#### [Angular Date Pipes](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Try this,

1. Import the {DatePipe} from '@angular/common' and include this in your main module.
2. Use DatePipe in your ts code where you wish to convert the date into a format that you want to change and use transform method and change it in the form you want.
3. Also do not forget to initialize the DatePipe in your constructor,

Try this code

```
let myDate = new Date(); 
console.log(this.datepipe.transform(myDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the date format before sending it in httpClient.post like this:

You can give your date from your object in its input argument, I'm hardcoding a date string here:

```
var date = new Date('2010-10-11T00:00:00+05:30');

var formattedDateString = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' +  date.getFullYear();

var dateToSend = new Date(formattedDateString);
```

Now you can attach this date in post request.

Comment: The problem is not to transform the date. The problem ist to influence the mapping when JSON is generated.

Comment: You should give more details. Make a plnkr if possible.